# Derived Generic Class Doesn't See Parent's Variables

Tags: c#, proxy, abstract-class, derived-class

I am trying to insolate classes from others setting or changing data in the class.  I have chosen to use an abstract base class called Parent and then two derived abstract classes called DerivedA and DerivedB. Then, using Assembly, I get the derived abstract classes from Parent.  Then, I use generics to derive a concrete class, ConcreteGeneric, to hopefully fill in the values of the abstract classes .

The problem I am having is that when I get into my concrete class, I do not have access (see) the parent class members/properties.  Maybe this design is all wrong, but this is the ideal way I would like to solve it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated... and save the hair that is falling off my head. ;)

Code is attached.

I have documented what I would like in the code.  To be able to access and see the public variables in the parent classes.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public abstract class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DerivedA : Parent
{
    public string DerivedAString { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DerivedB : Parent
{
    public string DerivedBString { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedFromA : DerivedA
{
    public string DerivedFromAString { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteGeneric<T> where T : Parent
{
    private string _jsonString = "";
    public string HeaderString
    {
        get
        {
            return _jsonString;
        }
        set
        {
            /// I want to be able to see the Derived classes parameters 
            /// here.  Like   'DerivedB.DerivedBString'  if T is type DerivedB 
            _jsonString = value;
        }
    }
}

public class RunItClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Type[] types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Parent)).GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Parent)).GetTypes()
            .Where(myType => myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Parent))))
        {
            var genType = typeof(ConcreteGeneric<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            Type genericType = (Type)genType;

            object genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
            dynamic dynamicObj = Convert.ChangeType(genericInstance, genericType);

            /// Note that when I drop into the 'set' method on this dynamic object, I cannot see the 
            /// paramters of the parent class, which is 'DerivedA' on the first item in this loop. 
            dynamicObj.HeaderString = "Testing";

            // Testing here
            if (genericType == typeof(ConcreteGeneric<DerivedA>))
            {
                // ?? I CANNOT see all of the variables in 'DerivedA' ??
                ConcreteGeneric<DerivedA> da = (ConcreteGeneric<DerivedA>)genericInstance;

                /// I CAN see all of the variables in 'DerivedA' and also 'Parent'.  This is what I
                /// am after, but I want to be able to use the ConcreteGeneric<![CDATA[>]]> to accomplish this.
                /// Please help.  :)
                DerivedFromA dfa = new DerivedFromA();

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note your title is misleading - your generic class doesn't have a parent

Answer (score 1):

The code inside your `ConcreteGeneric<T>` class has to work with *any* `T` that you might decide to give it. Since you've constrained `T` to `Parent` that means you can access any of `Parent's` properties.

You can say "*I want to be able to see the Derived classes parameters here*", but what if you created a `ConcreteGeneric<DerivedA>`? Then there wouldn't be any `DerivedBString` property there for you to access.

What you might be able to do is to expose your `T` directly inside `ConcreteGeneric<T>`:

```
public T Item { get; }
```

Then you'll be able to cast your `genericType` to a `ConcreteGeneric<DerivedA>`, and access `.Item`:

```
var concreteDerivedA = (ConcreteGeneric<DerivedA>)genericType;
string s = conceteDerivedA.Item.DerivedAString;
```

That leaves you with the question of how `Item` is set. If you enforce that it must have a parameterless constructor, you can do this:

```
public class ConcreteGeneric<T> where T : Parent, new()
{
    public T Item { get; } = new T();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `string s = conceteDerivedA.Item.DerivedAString;`?

Comment: No problem. Great answer.

Comment: canton7:  Thank you so much for this response.  I have to admit I am a bit of a newby with C#.  I am confused on one point.  When you say:

var concreteDerivedA = (ConcreteGeneric<DerivedA>)genericType;

I am concerned about the DerivedA part as the type in there brackets.  I can see 30 classes that will enter into the Concrete class as <T> and I can't 'if-else if' for all of those.  Maybe you could rewrite where you would put that without making it specific just to DerivedA but to T.  Do you understand my confusion?  Again, thanks for your help!!

Comment: There are two answers to that. If all of these classes are different and have different properties, then you're going to have to have different code which deals with them. There's no way around that. You can't have completely different DerivedA and DerivedB types, then write code which handles both of them in the same way. On the other hand, if your derived types have some things in common, then you can write interfaces/base classes which specify these common properties, then you can write common code which accesses them. Overall though I really don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: OK, perhaps I am not asking my question properly.  Sorry.

What I want to do is is set all of my properties in the Parent and all abstract derived classes by passing in a JSON string.  So what if I have an abstract method like:

public abstract void SetJSONString(string jsonString);

And I would then like to implement this in the Concrete class and then have it attempt to set all of the variable in DerivedA and DerivedB from this string.  I am trying this but failing.  Thanks.